# Draw connected components in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been going through the Learning OpenCV book.

I was trying to do something useful with the PyrSegmentation method in chapter 5:

```
void f(IplImage* src, IplImage* dst) 
{
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvSeq* comp = NULL;

    cvPyrSegmentation( src, dst, storage, &comp, 4, 200, 50 );     
    int n_comp = comp->total;

    for( int i=0; i < n_comp; i++ ) {
    CvConnectedComp* cc = (CvConnectedComp*) cvGetSeqElem( comp, i );
    // do_something_with( cc );
    }
cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );
}
```

I can't seem to draw the results on an image.

I have tried a few things, including creating a new image, blanking it out, and running a loop with something line the following:

```
if (inputKey == 32)
{
  // Draw surface
  cvZero(surface);
  cvDrawContours( surface, cc->contour, cvScalarAll(255), cvScalarAll(255), 100);
  cvShowImage( "Contour", surface);

  printf("Show new surface (%d)...\n", i);
}
```

However no matter what I do I end up with an empty image. There does appear to be valid data being returned, I just can't seem to display it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If you use c++ you should switch to `cv::Mat` instead of `IplImage` and use the c++ functions instead of c functions, if possible. About your code: Try to add a `cvWaitKey(0)` or `cvWaitKey(30) after your printf or after your cvShowImage to give OpenCV some time to display the image.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have a cvWaitKey(0) in the loop but did not display it in the code snippet. I am just getting a blank image for display. Pressing the space key shows another blank image until the last contour...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is cvPyrSegmentation does not populate set the contour member of CvConnectedComponent. Per the documentation one needs to calculate this themselves. I am working on this, and have a question posted here if anyone is looking for an answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433662/display-regions-detected-by-cvpyrsegmentation-in-opencv